# Can I render one layer with perspective camera and other layer with ortographic and compose both?

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes

I have two layers: one has to be rendered with orthographic camera in order to not mess with proportions of objects and other layer has to be rendered with perspective camera. Any way to achieve this? Compositor maybe?

Comment: The compositor does indeed compose.  Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: I kinda figured out how to do it. I created two scenes, one with orthographic camera, and other scene with perspective camera. Then composed rendered scenes. It works, but it feels like there is a faster solution to it.

Comment: It would be useful if you edited your question to reflect that, perhaps with some screenshots of your compositor nodes and some additional information.

Comment: As far as i know, the camera is specific for the entire scene. You cannot create two different cameras in one scene. Your solution is indeed the way to go.